# Union of two tables and count with where condition

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework2, union

I have to write the following query in zend-framework2

```
select count(*) from  
(
    select * from table1
    UNION
    select * from table2
)
as a
where col1 = condition1 and col2 = condition2;
```

I have done union of two tables using -

```
$select1 = new Select('table1');
$select2 = new Select("table2");
$select1->combine($select2);
```

I don't know how to give an alias after doing the union of two tables and how to get the count of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `$select1->combine($select2);` -

```
$sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->adapter);
$select_string = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select1);

$sql_string = 'SELECT * FROM (' . $select_string . ') AS select_union WHERE col1 = condition1 and col2 = condition2';
$statement = $this->tableGateway->adapter->createStatement($sql_string);
$resultSet = $statement->execute();
$total_records = count($resultSet);
```

`$resultSet` gives data.

`$total_records` gives total no. of records.

Comment: I have written where condition using zend\Db\where. How to add $where to it.